# Dropdown list options

Tags: c#, html

I am using this code on my Master page and wants to display option name on the reffered page

```
<select name=menu onchange="location.href=(menu.options[menu.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="http:google.com">Google</option> 
<option value="http:myurl.com">URL</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: And what? BTW, should not it be `http://`?

Comment: I think you forgot to ask the question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` to refer to event source object instead of `menu` the `name` of html element. You also have wrong url form and need to change it from `http:google.com` to `http://google.com`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/qDu6g/1/)**

```
<select name=menu onchange="window.location.href=(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option> 
    <option value="http://www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</option> 
</select>​
```